# npm suddenly stopped working

Tags: node.js, proxy, npm

My npm for unknown reason stopped working (installing, updating stuff), although it did work all the previous time, I didn't update nodejs and basically didn;t do anything.

So, I tried to run npm install and it sort of started showing that it was in progress, but it lasted for about 10-15 minutes and then failed.
I looked through different questions on stackoverflow but didn't find the solution.

Then, I reinstalled NodeJS, did `npm update -g npm`, but this command also didn't work. `npm -v` gives me v2.10.1 and `node -v` gives v0.12.4

Here's the screenshot of my console just in case:
[image: console screenshot]

Has anyone encountered that issue? Could you suggest any solutions to that please?

#### UPDATE

Here's another screenshot when the whole process is finished:
[image]

So, am I behind a proxy? [WhatIsMyIP](https://www.whatismyip.com) says that I don't have a proxy...

Comment: If you enter the URL of a download that failed into a browser are you able to download the file?

Comment: It just may be that your network or npm is down. Unfortunately, this happens way more often than you'd expect it to. So, maybe the problem is gone within a short amount of time, just wait… you may also be interested in http://status.npmjs.org/

Comment: @ErikGillespie No, the links don't work :(

Comment: @GoloRoden Well, it's already been for like 3 hours..  BTW, thanks for the npm status link!